# Calculate 3rd point of a triangle, given 2 points and all angles in 2D

Tags: triangles, triangulation

I have stumbled upon an interesting problem. I tried to find an answer here but there are just too many similar threads which did not really help me, so I was trying to figure it out by myself. 
The task was to create a formula (because it was a programming task) for finding out coordinates of the third vertex (**C**) in a triangle as well as its distance from the opposite side (**AB**), given two other vertices as well as all the angles. It was adapted from [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation#Distance_to_a_point_by_measuring_two_fixed_angles). Finding out the distance was not a problem, however, it was hard to find coordinates of the third point.
Following is my method. I would be glad if you could check it and maybe suggest a better solution.

The first step was finding out coordinates of a point on **AB**, which lies on perpendicular from the missing vertex. $$S[S_x,S_y] \in AB \bigcap h\\ |h| = |AB|\frac{sin (\alpha) sin (\beta)}{sin (\alpha + \beta)} $$
Coordinates for all the points (therefore for **S** as well) on AB (where $\lambda$ is a scalar) : $$S=[A_x+\lambda(B_x-A_x); A_y+\lambda(B_y-A_y)]$$

Since we know that $|AS| = \frac{h}{tan(\alpha)}$, after substituing we find out that $$\lambda=\frac{h}{tan(\alpha)\sqrt{(B_x-A_x)^2+(B_y-A_y)^2}}$$ or $\lambda=\frac{cot(\alpha)*h}{\sqrt{(B_x-A_x)^2+(B_y-A_y)^2}}$ if you wish.

The second step was defining the perpendicular. We know the coordinates of one point which lies on it (**S**) as well as it's direction (normal vector to vector **AB**, specifically $n = (A_y - B_y; B_x - A_x)$). Thus, all the points on this line have coordinates $$C=[S_x + \kappa(A_y-B_y); S_y + \kappa(B_x-A_x)]$$ where $\kappa$ is again a scalar.

We also know that $|SC|=h$, so we get this equality
$$
\sqrt{(C_x - S_x)^2 + (C_y-S_y)^2} = h
$$
which after solving gives
$$
\kappa = \frac{h}{\sqrt{(A_y-B_y)^2+(B_x-A_x)^2}}
$$

Now it is just a matter of putting it all together. Returning to our definition of C, we know all the variables.

$$
C_x=S_x + \kappa(A_y-B_y)\\
\Downarrow\\
C_x=A_x+\lambda(B_x-A_x) + \kappa(A_y-B_y)\\
\Downarrow\\
C_x=A_x+\frac{cot(\alpha)(B_x-A_x)h}{\sqrt{(B_x-A_x)^2+(B_y-A_y)^2}} + \frac{h(A_y-B_y)}{\sqrt{(A_y-B_y)^2+(B_x-A_x)^2}}
$$

And analogically for $C_y$

$$
C_y=A_y+\frac{cot(\alpha)(B_y-A_y)h}{\sqrt{(B_x-A_x)^2+(B_y-A_y)^2}} + \frac{h(B_x-A_x)}{\sqrt{(A_y-B_y)^2+(B_x-A_x)^2}}
$$

And these two lines are for the computer to solve. My question is: could it be done in a *better* way? I suppose it is correct, the code works well. But I am personally very interested in different ways how to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: How about this: we know the coordinates of two vertices, so we must know an equation of line through $AB$. Since we know the angles, then we can find equation of lines (just rotate the line accordingly, since we know positions of $A,B$ we will know which direction (anticlockwise/clockwise) the rotation has to be) that coincide with edges $AC,BC$ and coordinate of $C$ will be the intersection point of two lines. I'm completely newbie at programming, sorry if it doesnt work or it is worse method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make atleast 2 conditions:
1. When $Ax>Bx$
2. When $Ax < Bx$

Even then it fails on this particual coordinates: $$464(Ax) \ 741(Ay)\ 22(alfa) \     237(Bx) \ 589(By)\ 85(Beta).$$

It fails when $$Ay > By\ Ax > Bx \ but \ alfa < beta.$$
[image]

Comment: I actually considered that in code, I just did not mention it here because it seemed irrelevant. Finding the second C is done the same way with negated normal vector, specifically (B_y-A_y; A_x-B_x)